# The notification shows Mon Aug 26. 9:16 PM on my desktop but Mon 9:17 PM on my laptop

Tags: gnome

At the top of my Ubuntu desktop it says Mon Aug 26 and the time. On my Ubuntu laptop it does NOT show the date, just Mon + time. I want the date on my laptop. Any thoughts?  My Desktop is 18.04.3 LTS with Gnome 3.28.2. My laptop is the same Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS) and the same Gnome (3.28.2).

The GNOME-tweak suggestion solved my problem. I installed it on my laptop and easily added the date. Thanks to everyone for their help.

Comment: You haven't said what release, but use the tweaks tool (`gnome-tweaks` or `unity-tweaks` depending on your release/desktop used)

Comment: Might just be able to click where the time is, and should open a box with the settings option at the bottom.  Works with unity.